# Azure Yaml to Powerhell value being lost in parameter

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline that is calling a PowerShell file using `@AzureCLI@2` but at the top of the script I appear to be losing a value passed in which is the directory I want to load a file from.

If I perform this Task in Yaml:

`- powershell: Get-ChildItem -Path ${{ parameters.artifactFolder }} -recurse`

I can see outputs as such:

```
    Directory: C:\a\2\s\firewall\Parameters\output\myDir


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
-a----         6/20/2023   1:30 PM        3804260 parameters.json
```

The next Yaml task:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Remove Resource Locks
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    ScriptPath: '${{ parameters.artifactFolder }}/powershell/fw.removeLocks.ps1'
    arguments: >
      -firewallOutputFolder "${{ parameters.artifactFolder }}"
      -action "Remove"
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

Passes in the directory. With the PowerShell script, the following code is at the start of the file:

```
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $firewallOutputFolder,
    [ValidateSet("Create", "Remove")]
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $action
    
    try 
    {
    
        # Either remove or create locks for Firewall and FW Policy
        Write-Host "First WH......................"
        Write-Host $firewallOutputFolder
        Write-Host "$($firewallOutputFolder)\Parameters\output"
    
    
        $folder = $firewallOutputFolder
    
        # Loop output files i.e. deployment files
        $fwFiles = Get-ChildItem $firewallOutputFolder -Directory
        foreach($fwFile in $fwFiles)
        {
            $fwParameters = "$($firewallOutputFolder)\$($fwFile.name)\parameters.json"
}
    }
```

The outputs from the first batch of `write-host`:

```
First WH......................

\Parameters\output
```

The value being passed in is now empty/null

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the value is vanishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **PowerShell script** is **missing the `param(...)` enclosure around your individual parameter declarations** - see the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters) help topic.

Therefore:

```bash
# Parameter declarations must be enclosed in param(...)
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string] $firewallOutputFolder
  ,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [ValidateSet('Create', 'Remove')]
  [string] $action
)

# ...
```

Unfortunately, *forgetting* `param(...)` effectively results in *quiet failure*:

- What you mean to be *parameter* declarations are interpreted as `[string]` *casts* from *nonexistent variables* (which evaluate to `$null`, unless a strict mode is in effect).
- The *attribute* decorations (`[Parameter()]`, `[ValidateSet()]`) are effectively *ignored*.
- As a result, each such mistaken declaration outputs the *empty string* (effectively the same as `[string] $null`) instead of declaring parameters.

Therefore, **your script doesn't declare any parameters at all**, which means that not only does it not enforce *mandatory* arguments, but happily accepts *any* number of (positional) arguments, which are then only reflected in the automatic `$args` variable.

---

This quiet failure due to what should arguably be a *syntax error* is unfortunate.
[GitHub issue #10614](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10614) asks that such cases either be prevented syntactically or at least generate a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some of the [AzureCLI@2 Tasks examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines), it looks like the arguments are positional args and not named. I didn't see any examples using named arguments like shown in your yaml file. Perhaps try...

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Remove Resource Locks
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    ScriptPath: '${{ parameters.artifactFolder }}/powershell/fw.removeLocks.ps1'
    arguments: "'${{ parameters.artifactFolder }}' 'Remove'"
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

I'm unsure whether you will need the inside single-quotes in the argument string.